# split the navigation menu by the " | " in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, navigation

Is there a simple way to split my navigation menu by the ' | ' for example ?
This is my menu :

```
(home  about us  our work   connect us)
```

So I need like this one :

```
(home   |   about us   |   our work   |   connect us)
```

and when the editor add a new item  in ( *Appearance->Menus*)  it must add the ' | ' automatically .
Any idea ?
php html css javascript  ... no problem

Comment: You need to change the HTML template. We cannot tell you what your HTML template looks like and therefore you must do it yourself.

Comment: thank you but ...
no i create my theme 
it a special question about to split every item in my nav menu .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('after' => '|')); ?>
```

For style

```
   .main-nav li 
    {
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
    }

  .main-nav li:first-child
   {
        border-left: 0;

   }
```

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu(array('container_class'=>'main-nav','container'=>'nav','after' => '|')); ?>

Comment: thanks a lot.... great technique. but i don't know how to style it cuz the line shown under the menu

Comment: @HadiOmary: is that helped or not?

Comment: mmmm thanks it is work and i add for next li       .main-nav ul ul>li{
 border:0;
 }

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to add line and check the

***[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bf9h/)***

Here is simple code

```
<div class="verticalLine">

home  

</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.verticalLine {
    border-left: 2px solid ;
    display:inline;
    padding-left:5px ;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.Just a newbie trying to help:)

Comment: Use an UL and list elements for a navigation!

Comment: Just showing him how to add vertical line. Other part is on him i guess.

Comment: i know about to put them in line and know about the html and style but i only need to split them automatically so let me say 
(<?php wp_nav_menu(array('container'=>'nav'));  split_by ("  |  ")?>)

is there some thing like ....... thanx all ya

Comment: @HadiOmary You need to change the styles of the `li` items. This is called CSS and there's plenty of tutorials online about it.

Comment: @HadiOmary To actually put a '|' character into navigation in this manner doesn't help with semantics and accessibility. You'd be better using CSS as per the answer and comments.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to my site using jquery.

```
 $('ul#mainNav > li').not('ul#mainNav > li:last').append("&nbsp;|&nbsp;");
```

You would need to update the selector to match your own navigation.